# Max Mod Principle

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

I'm stuck with the following exercise:

Let $f$ be holomorphic on an open set containing $\bar{D}$, the closed unit disk.  Prove that there exists a $z_0 \in \partial D$ such that

$$\bigg|\frac{1}{z_0} - f(z_0)\bigg| \ge 1 $$

I know that I need to use the maximum modulus principle, but I am not sure where to begin, besides proving by contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give you more detail beyond David C. Ullrich's post. In fact, you don't have to use maximum modulus principle explicitly. But you need to use the idea to prove it. 
We have
$$
\int_\gamma \left(\frac1{z} - f(z)\right)\,dz=\int_\gamma \frac1{z} \,dz=2\pi i\tag{1}
$$
Use contradiction to prove that if condition were not true, $(1)$ would not be held.

Suppose for all $z \in \partial D$, there is $|1/z - f(z)| < 1$. Then
$$\left|\int_\gamma(1/z - f(z))\,dz\right|\leqslant\int_\gamma|1/z - f(z)|\,dz<2\pi$$

Comment: I'm not sure why you posted this answer. Aren't you doing exactly what David Ullrich suggested below?

Comment: No, I just want to give more detail of proof. Since David Ullrich's answer is not voted, I think it may not be enough for others to understand. My answer is voted so my guess could be right. Also my answer is very different from David Ullrich's.

Comment: I understand what you did, but I don't see the contradiction?

Comment: All are explained in the hidden text. The contradiction is that if $\forall z∈∂D, |1/z−f(z)|<1$, then $\left|\int_\gamma(1/z - f(z))\,dz\right|<2\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Define $g(z)=1/z - f(z)$. Say $\gamma$ is the unit circle. What can you say about $$\int_\gamma g(z)\,dz\,\,?$$